# Googlemaps marker not showing on user location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a googlemap on my application but the marker is not showing where the location of the user is and the marker is supposed to be there and everytime the user update its location the marker should be updated also. Can you help me guys? Thanks :)

```
public class GPSRenter extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleAPIClient;
MarkerOptions options;
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(googleServicesAvailable()){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsrenter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        initMap();
    }else{

    }

}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public boolean googleServicesAvailable(){
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }else if(api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect to Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
//        goToLocationZoom(39.008224, -76.8984527, 15);
//        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mGoogleAPIClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
    mGoogleAPIClient.connect();
}


LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleAPIClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 18);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLatitude()))
                .snippet("I am here");

        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);

        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you check onLocationChanged is called or not ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana - it is called. the `animateCamera` is working well. It's just the marker is my problem sir.

Comment: Set an icon for your marker.

Comment: try to add title instead of snippet and map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));

Comment: @BatzPogi Why is mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); commented out? You mean that the blue dot and the marker you have added do not match?

Comment: I think you need to declare MarkerOption out side this method and try to update you location on MarkerOption instead of create new MarkerOption on each time.

Comment: @AlWld - Because I'm getting the current position of the user not the location to be defiend by the user.

Comment: @HareshChhelana - I'll put it on `onCreate`?

Comment: @MohitTrivedi - It still doesnt show my marker..

Comment: you tried with CameraUpdateFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Batz Pogi try to this hope this can help you..

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLatitude()))
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yourImage)));
```

For more please follow below link..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Comment: Where should i put the `marker` after i initialize it?

Comment: I figured out how sir! Thanks, you saved my day! Hahaha